# When are you required to change the `authoring_version` for forkless runtime upgrades?

Tags: polkadot, runtime-upgrade, chainspec, authorship

In the Substrate documentation [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/upgrades#runtime-versioning) and the Substrate reference documentation [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/node_testing/client/sc_executor/struct.RuntimeVersion.html#structfield.authoring_version) it says the `authoring_version` *"is the version of the authorship interface. An authoring node will not attempt to author blocks unless this is equal to its native runtime"*.

In [this old pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/600/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR98) for Substrate the `authoring_version` was incremented for Kusama but I am not clear why that was necessary.
It appears to have changed because the following were changed since `paint` was renamed to `pallet` and those block authoring related dependencies changed:

- `pallet-authorship` used instead of `paint-authorship`
- `pallet-authority-discovery` used instead of `paint-authority-discovery`
- `pallet-babe` used instead of `paint-babe`

Note that the babe pallet is used for authoring blocks, the authorship pallet is used to fetch the current block author and to create and submit unsigned extrinsics, and the authority-discovery pallet is used to *"retrieve the current set of authorities"*.

Another situation when I think it should change is if you changed consensus mechanism, for example [this old pull request here](https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/node/pull/215/files#diff-0ec06ea58bd455f09ce6b3bb4c2c1c0d37bda51c1e1be2151c560c9c973959ecR218) for the DataHighway changed it from Babe to Aura, but I think it was incorrect that they (me) did not change the `authoring_version`.

In the Substrate reference documentation [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/node_testing/client/sc_executor/struct.NativeVersion.html#method.can_author_with) for `can_author_with`, instead of checking the `authoring_version`, it checks [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/node_testing/client/sc_executor/struct.NativeVersion.html#structfield.can_author_with) if the *"authoring runtimes (`spec_versions`) that this native runtime supports"*
matches the other version that is provided to determine whether it supports authoring blocks, where the other version may be associated with the version provided for a forkless runtime upgrade, which leads me to think that the `spec_version` would typically get bumped alongside an `authoring_version` bump.

It also says in the Substrate source code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/version/src/lib.rs#L155) that *"bug fixes should result in an increment of `spec_version` and possibly `authoring_version`, absolutely not `impl_version` since they change the semantics of the runtime"*. I assume that means the `authoring_version` would only need to be incremented in the case of a bug fix or other change related to block authoring dependencies.

In the Substrate source code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L121) it says that *"Per convention: if the runtime behavior changes, increment `spec_version` and set `impl_version` to 0. If only runtime implementation changes and behavior does not, then leave `spec_version` as is and increment `impl_version`."*.
I assume that the convention also requires that for changes related to authorship then when the runtime behaviour changes but the implementation does not change then you either increment `authoring_version` or set `authoring_version` to 0.
I am not sure what they mean when they say runtime "behavior".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind `authoring_version` was to indicate that something in the api between the runtime and the node changed that makes the node unable to build new blocks. We almost never bumped this version and with the removal of the native runtime this `authoring_version` will probably be deprecated anyway. If you break something in the authoring interface like `apply_extrinsic` you would probably find it out anyway by having the block production fail ;) Currently it would spam your logs with "node upgrade" required.

TLDR: Set the version to some sane value like `1` for now. We will need to have some more discussion on the future of this `authoring_version` and if we maybe deprecate it or change it and improve the documentation on when to bump this.