# Do I need to bump the versions of a new release manually before making a runtime upgrade from a Polkadot release-v0.9.xx?

Tags: polkadot, rococo, rococo-local

I am running a rococo fork and used Polkadot `[release-v0.9.18][1]` to make a runtime upgrade.

I upgraded the chain initially, but didn’t see a difference in the chain. So then I realised I need to bump the versions as mentioned [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases) in the docs.

My question is: how do I know what versions to bump? For example, do i need to manually bump the authoring version, by checking the release and seeing is that is a requirement. Is there notes in the release that talk specifically to that?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56873179/substrate-has-runtime-versioning-what-is-the-purpose-and-use-case-for-these#:~:text=Runtime%20versioning%20is%20an%20important,feature%20of%20Substrate%20based%20blockchains.&text=spec_version%20is%20used%20to%20signify,affect%20consensus%20in%20the%20network.

Answer (score 1):

As noted here:

- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/forkless-upgrade

When upgrading the chain, you need to manually increment the `spec_version`.

Here are the changes for `release-v0.9.28`, notice that the only value that was updated was the `spec_version`:

```
/// Runtime version (Polkadot).
#[sp_version::runtime_version]
pub const VERSION: RuntimeVersion = RuntimeVersion {
    spec_name: create_runtime_str!("polkadot"),
    impl_name: create_runtime_str!("parity-polkadot"),
    authoring_version: 0,
-   spec_version: 9270,
+   spec_version: 9280,
    impl_version: 0,
    #[cfg(not(feature = "disable-runtime-api"))]
    apis: RUNTIME_API_VERSIONS,
    #[cfg(feature = "disable-runtime-api")]
    apis: sp_version::create_apis_vec![[]],
    transaction_version: 13,
    state_version: 0,
};
```

> Note: `authoring_version` is rarely incremented.
>
> tldr: [When are you required to change the `authoring_version` for forkless runtime upgrades?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/984/when-are-you-required-to-change-the-authoring-version-for-forkless-runtime-upg/1055#1055)

More Info:

- https://docs.substrate.io/build/upgrade-the-runtime